# Elevation contours opengl

Tags: opengl

We are running our own graphical pipeline on an intel atom chip for my current project.

I am being told to implement elevation contours which should look like :

[image]

After  some search on the internet I managed to come up with a fragment shader like :

```
#version 130

varying lowp  vec4 colorVar; // That is my original color 
varying lowp  float heightVal; // I am passing gl_Position.y from vertex shader  

void main() 
{
    float f  = fract ( heightVal*0.1 );
    float df = fwidth( heightVal*0.1 );

    float g = smoothstep(df * 1.0, df * 2.0, f);

    float c = g;

    gl_FragColor = colorVar * vec4(c, c, c, 1.0);
}
```

Which seems to produce good results in a mountain model

[image]

But still draws contour lines in a flat model

[image]

I have three questions,

Why I am seeing contour lines even when the height is not changed?

Why are the contour lines moving the camera?

I think I didn't understand what is actually happening when I pass height to "fract" function and that is the root cause of my problems. I can understand that it will repeat the pattern if we use gl_FragCoord just like [here](https://thebookofshaders.com/09/). But I can't understand how it operates with the height. 
So my final question is what is the relation of how "fract" behaves with varying height?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `gl_Position.y` then you are passing through a coordinate in clip-space (which are effectively screen coordinates, but before the perspective divide).

This has nothing to do with the height of the model in world-space.

Comment: Thanks!.  I am using:   vec4 temp = modelViewMatrix*vertexPosAttr; heightVal = temp.y; instead but my contours still not depending on the height and moving with the camera. Do you have other suggestions

Comment: You need to exclude "view" from the calculation.

vec4 temp = modelMatrix*vertexPosAttr; heightVal = temp.y;

Comment: Thanks a lot no more dancing with the camera. I want to be able to control my counter line every x meters(eg 50 meters) . But I didn't understand how fract function is operating the height value. It seems vec4 temp = modelMatrix*vertexPosAttr; heightVal = temp.y * step ; smaller the step bigger the contours but I still can't imagine why. Maybe I should make a seperate question for that.